# setting up linear regression for stock and index returns

Tags: python, linear-regression

Not so much a coding question as a question about how to set up my regression.

I have a year long time series of prices for a stock and an index, then I have a percentage returns for the stock and index where each day following the first day of the year is calculated as a percentage gain or loss with respect to the first day of the year. So if the stock was valued at 100$ on day 1, and 105$ on day 30, that would be a 5% return instance.

The y column is the stock returns and the x column is the index returns, so for day 30 there was a 5% gain for the stock, but maybe there was a 4% gain for the index, so there will be a scatter point on my regression plot for the coordinate (4, 5).

There are 365 days in the year so there are 365 points. The year I'm looking at has a fairly linear relationship, and I've set up a regression for it since it is a fairly common way to assess stock performance in finance. From regression we get Jensen's Measure, for which the y-intercept and slope of the regression tell us important things about the stock's returns once risk has been accounted for.

I'm wondering how you guys would set up a regression line in this case. Mine is as follows so feel free to pick apart or throw it out altogether.

```
df60 = pd.DataFrame()
df60['X'] = np.asarray(list23)  # Index returns
df60['Y'] = np.asarray(list21)  # Stock returns
df60

X = df60.X[:, None]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, df60.Y, random_state=0)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

x_range = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 100)
y_range = model.predict(x_range.reshape(-1, 1))
```

I set it up this way mainly because I needed to plot it in Plotly and this was the example formatting they used, but like for starters I don't think random_state should be used.

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is to create a regression plot of the data then you can do it even easier using seaborn library like:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df60 = pd.DataFrame({'stock returns':np.asarray(list23),
                     'index returns':np.asarray(list21)})

sns.regplot(df60['stock returns'],df60['index returns'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well I need to use Plotly to show it in dash. So we need to keep the basic formatting with sklearn and train/test/split, but perhaps change target variables and training methodology based on the nature of the data.